# PHPMailer, SMTP Error: Could not authenticate

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm pretty sure that there are many questions out there regarding this problem.I don't seem to get my solution.

I'm using PHPMailer to mail through my php script.It was totally working few days back but today i tried doing it again,it didn't work.

```
               require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
               $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

                    $message="Hello there";
                    $mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
                    $statement=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO usertable VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    $zero=0;
                    $null=null;
                    $state='Delhi';

                    $statement->bind_param("sssssiiissssi",$email,$firstname,$lastname,$name,$password,$zero,$confirmcode,$zero,$null,$null,$null,$state,$zero);
                    $statement->execute();


                     try
                     {
                    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
                    $mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
                    $mail->Username = 'support@mydomain.com';                 // SMTP username
                    $mail->Password = 'mvdctadwzkiibtot';                           // SMTP password
                    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
                    $mail->Port =  465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

                    $mail->setFrom('From @mydomain', 'mydomain');

                    $mail->addAddress($email);               // Name is optional
                    $mail->addReplyTo('support@mydomain.com', 'For any queries mail back to support@foodquo.com');
                    // $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
                    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
                    $mail->WordWrap = 50;

                    //  $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
                    // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
                    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

                    $mail->Subject = 'Confirm your email ID';
                    $mail->Body    = $message;
                    //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
                     $mail->send();
                     }
                     catch(Exception $e)
                     {
                          $mysqli->rollback();
                     $response=array(
                            'status'=>'mailFailed',
                            'errorer'=>$e->getMessage(),

                         );

                     }
                  echo json_encode($response);
```

**NOTE**

1. I have my domain registered on *Hostgator*.
2. The email is present inside the cpanel and i can configure it from there.It doesn't have any password.So `$mail->Password` should not be an issue.

Given Below is the error that i have been getting , what could be the possible solution? Thanks!

> > SMPT Error :Could not authenticate.

Comment: try commenting the $mail->isSMTP();

Comment: You are using tls..You should use: $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

Comment: @Satty  Could not instantiate mail function. This is what i get when i comment the `$mail->isSMTP();`

Comment: @Satty SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. when i  change it to `smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: $mail->Port =  587;

Comment: `$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'` why u use gmail as host while using hostgator as hosting? and this `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` try using `ssl` instead.

Comment: @Satty back to square one , `SMTP Error: Could not authenticate`

Comment: @HendraNucleo what do i use then?

Comment: @HendraNucleo `SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.` Same thing.

Comment: Use the one from hostgator. Using gmail on development in local is worked, but when you upload it on live hosting you need host, port from your hosting. Asking your customer support for port, and use username & password from email account u created from cPanel. My case with namecheap as hosting before.

Comment: Hostgator doesn't have the password for their mail.It is like an utility , you log in to your account and then there you have the mail utility.Yeah , i will ask my customer support as well but i did check it live , it did work few days ago. @HendraNucleo

Comment: As a sample i was giving this info from namecheap if i want send email out from server. Absolutely not gmail for `host`. Sample: `Incoming Server: premium1.web-hosting.com IMAP Port: 993 POP3 Port: 995 & Outgoing Server: premium1.web-hosting.com SMTP Port: 465`. 
========

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121276/discussion-between-hendra-nucleo-and-botjr).

Comment: The appearance of your error messages suggests you're using an old version of PHPMailer. Make sure you're running [the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: @Synchro let me change it as well. Okay?

Answer (score -1):

if u are using gmail smptp service use:

```
$mail->Username = 'emailid@gmail.com';                 // Gmail username
                    $mail->Password = 'mvdctadwzkiibtot'; //gmail password
```